# Does myBatis provide some method such as refreshAndLock?

Tags: java, mybatis, toplink

I'm new to mybatis, I want to know does mybatis provide some method such as refreshAndLock like toplink? How can I make sure that the record I select can't be modified by other thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mybatis does not have such method. mybatis is too low level for this. You need to do that manually.

For pessimistic locking this would look like this:

`<select id="refreshAndLock" resultType="YourType">
       SELECT * FROM TableStoringYourType WHERE id = #{id}
       FOR UPDATE
   </select>`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Ibatis does not support any locking, not even optimistic, let alone pessimistic locking.

Most Java applications use optimistic locking only, may be you can give it a try.
You can add optimistic locking to iBatis yourself, here it is explained how to do that with spring : [optimistic-locking-on-ibatis](http://matejtymes.blogspot.de/2010/11/optimistic-locking-on-ibatis.html)